# pandas: groupby sum conditional on other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E'],
              'b':['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
              'c':[20, 5, 12, 8, 15, 10, 25, 13]})

   a  b   c
0  A  Y  20
1  B  Y   5
2  B  N  12
3  C  Y   8
4  C  Y  15
5  D  N  10
6  D  N  25
7  E  N  13
```

i would like to groupby column 'a', check if any of column 'b' is 'Y' or True and keep that value and then just sum on 'c'

the resulting dataframe should look like this

```
   a  b   c
0  A  Y  20
1  B  Y  17
2  C  Y  23
3  D  N  35
4  E  N  13
```

i tried the below but get an error

```
df.groupby('a')['b'].max()['c'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `agg` with `max` and `sum`. Max on column 'b' indeed works because 'Y' > 'N' == True

```
print(df.groupby('a', as_index=False).agg({'b': 'max', 'c': 'sum'}))

   a  b   c
0  A  Y  20
1  B  Y  17
2  C  Y  23
3  D  N  35
4  E  N  13
```

Comment: or ```df.groupby("a", as_index=False).agg({"b": "max", "c": "sum"})``` to avoid the ``reset_index``

Comment: That would still work as both boolean True > False, and string 'True' > 'False'. @sammywemmy, thanks I've updated the answer